# Simple local search function. Javascript and JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Building a 'fake' web browser and web pages that are all compiled locally in a windows form application. The whole thing operates offline.

I need to build a search function on one of the web pages I've made. Obviously theirs no server involved, so I have to have the data extracted and displayed from a local source. I've used 'Jput' before in a [previous project](http://fooda.website/) so i was thinking about having a Json file that can be called. The site is a fake social network, so when a user searches a name or phrase, it displays related results (profiles) either on a separate page or within the current doc. Jput is good, but its pretty limited when it comes to styling.

**QUESTION**

What would be the best way of doing this? How would I index all these results and how would the search engine work?

Let me know if more detail is needed for this question

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a normal Javascript array ( that can be stored as json) :

Example data:

```
var users=[
{name:"John",age:22}
{name:"Jack",age:23}
]
```

Now you can search after name:

```
document.body.innerHTML=users.filter(el=>el.name.split("Ja")[1]).map(el=>el.name).join("<br>");
```

This will show all users that names contain "Ja"inside of the document ( or any other html elem, can be based on users input).

You can easily show a users profile like this:

```
user=users.find(el=>el.name=="Jack");
for(key in user){
  alert(key+":"+user[key]);
}
```

This is just the beginning of what you can do with natives js, no need for libs etc.

Comment: Thanks! that's awesome! massive help!